# Why do I need an explicit downcast in an exhaustive switch expression?

Tags: dart, types, type-inference, switch-expression

Here's some dart code that seems interesting to me:

```dart
void main() {
  A<num> someA = B();
  A value = switch (someA) {
      B() => B(),
      C() => C(),
  };
}

sealed class A<T extends num> {}
final class B extends A<int> {}
final class C extends A<double> {}
```

If you try to compile this, you get an error about the switch statement: `A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'A<num>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'A<num>'.`

My question is, why doesn't the compiler infer the common parent type between the two? (Well, it sort of does I guess... by defaulting to `Object`.) If you wrote something like `var myThing = true ? 1.5 : 7;`, dart infers the expected type of `myThing` to be `num`. Why doesn't it do that here?

Of course, this is all fixed when you do

```dart
void main() {
  A<num> someA = B();
  A value = switch (someA) {
      B() => B() as A,
      C() => C() as A,
  };
}

sealed class A<T extends num> {}
final class B extends A<int> {}
final class C extends A<double> {}
```

instead. Also, it's worth noting that this issue is not present when the type parameter `<T extends num>` is not present -- so there's something about generic types that is preventing the compiler from inferring the expected type (or what I expected, at least).

Edit: There is an interesting difference between `switch`-expression behavior and list expressions (and if you combine them):

```dart
void main() {
  // `values_var` is `List<Object>`
  var values_var            = [B(), C()];
  List<A> values_List1      = [B(), C()];
  List<A<num>> values_List2 = [B(), C()];
  // all of the above compiles fine

  A<num> someA = B();
  
  // does not compile
  A value = switch (someA) {
      B() => B(),
      C() => C(),
  };

  // DOES compile
  List<A> value = switch (someA) {
      B() => [B()],
      C() => [C()],
  };
}
```

This is a clearer version of my original question: Why does type inference work as I expect for the lists, but not for the `switch`-expression (without lists)?

Comment: Same case for list btw, `final list = [B(), C()];` here `list` is `List<Object>`

Comment: Thanks! I played around with this and decided it actually helps refine my original question. Glad you brought this up.

Comment: I think this is related to the least upper bound algorithm dart uses for inference. There are a number of open issues relating to this you can see [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/labels/least-upper-bound), but [this one](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1618) is probably the main issue.

Comment: Totally right @mmcdon20, I found [this comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1618#issuecomment-1492760421) which seems to be exactly what I'm running into here

Comment: @mmcdon20 if you want to turn your last comment into an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one, since that github issue actually talks about releasing a change in Dart 3.4 that fixes my problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, why doesn't the compiler infer the common parent type between the two?

This is due to the least upper bound algorithm dart uses for type inference.

You can read about least upper bound here in the language specification:

https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf#Least%20Upper%20Bounds

In the dart language repo on github, there are a number of open issues relating to least upper bound not inferring the desired type (instead inferring an overly general type usually `Object`):

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/labels/least-upper-bound

The main issue that seems to be tracking this problem can be found here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1618

I also opened an issue relating to this myself a while ago, and the responses there are quite informative as well:

https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2953

---

> If you wrote something like `var myThing = true ? 1.5 : 7;`, dart infers the expected type of `myThing` to be `num`. Why doesn't it do that here?

My understanding is that least upper bound only comes into play when generics are involved.

The same class hierarchy without generics does not produce any errors.

```dart
void main() {
  A someA = B();
  A value = switch (someA) {
      B() => B(),
      C() => C(),
  };
}

sealed class A {}
final class B extends A {}
final class C extends A {}
```

---

> Why does type inference work as I expect for the lists, but not for the `switch`-expression (without lists)?

I'm not 100% certain on this, but my best guess here is that if you read the section in the language spec about [list literal inference](https://spec.dart.dev/DartLangSpecDraft.pdf#List%20Literal%20Inference), it mentions that list literals take into account a context type when determining the type.

If you read through the github issues linked above, it seems that the current issues surrounding least upper bounds occur when a context type is not accounted for.

Comment: Awesome! Great summary of those issues, those links were really helpful. I was also happy to see that [some improvements](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1618#issuecomment-1978809884) are coming soon (hopefully) in Dart 3.4!

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand this slightly modified version works as expected without the need for casting (Dart Version 3.3.0):

```
import 'dart:math';

sealed class A<T extends num> {}
final class B extends A<int> {}
final class C extends A<double> {}

void main() {
  
  var rand = Random();
  var someA = B();
  var value = switch (someA) {
      B() => B(),
      C() => C(),  // Dead code (message from the static analyzer).
  };
    
  print(value);
  print(value.runtimeType);
  
  var myThing = rand.nextDouble() > 0.5 ? 1.2:  1;
  print(myThing.runtimeType);
}
```

Note also that `myThing` is either inferred to an `int` or a `double`.

```
$ dart main.dart
Instance of 'B'
B
int
```

This issue might be of interest: [covariant generics](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/3565#issuecomment-1894569897). In Dart, if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `G<A>` is a subtype of `G<B>`.

Comment: Oh, wait... this is weird. The `runtimeType` in your example is `B`, but the dart analyzer thinks `value` is still an `Object` (I'm getting that by hovering over `value` in VSCode). Maybe this is an analyzer bug?

Comment: I think that is just the difference between the static analysis and the actual runtime type. In the example above the static analyzer cannot possible know what the type of `myThing` will be until the value of `rand.nextDouble()` is computed.

Comment: Oh... so because `int`/`double` aren't subtypes of `T` (which extends `num`), it can't infer the type, because there might be other kinds of `num`? Let me make a small experiment of this...

Comment: Okay, well it's not what I thought -- I tested replacing `num`/`int`/`double` with (`sealed`/`final`) classes like `MyNum`/`MyInt`/`MyDouble`, and I still ran into the same error in the `switch` expression.

Also, you said "In Dart, if A is a subtype of B, then G<A> is a subtype of G<B>". Following that logic, it is true that instances of either `B` or `C` are always `A<num>`, which you can see in my list example I just added. So why can the lists pick up on this but not the `switch`-expression?